# How to scroll youtube playlist with javascript

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using Selenium to automatically scroll a youtube list such as this:
[A youtube list](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=UUrp_UI8XtuYfpiqluWLD7Lw)

I'm using this to do the scrolling:

```
window.scrollTo(0,document.querySelector("ytd-playlist-video-list-renderer.style-scope").scrollHeight);
```

I'm found the querySelector from Firefox Css Selector
But I've got querySelector is null error.

What is the ideamatic way to achieve this?

Comment: You probably need to wait for the website to be loaded

Comment: Sorry people. I just change to a new selector and it works: div.ytd-playlist-video-list-renderer:nth-child(3)

Comment: are you trying to invoke the infinite scroll? Or just to a particular element/item?